# Page load time of websites

Tags: internet, dns, webserver, ping

I'm trying to find a solution to a "problem" which occurs when opening webpages.

When I'm opening to open any website (no matter which browser), for example www.stackexchange.com, it takes always 5 seconds until the page load begins (not until it is loaded). No matter which site I'm opening, it takes always pretty much 5 seconds, sometimes a little more, until anything happens. I'm not sure if it's the DNS lookup or what else it could be. I'm really no expert on this topic.

I'm on a mac with Mavericks installed and have a 32.000 mbit connection, which has no problems reaching it's full speed. It's just always taking a felt lifetime until anything happens.

I've tried to change the DNS addresses in the OSX's internet settings to Google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. The only difference I notice is that the page load after the five seconds seems faster. But as far as I know this can't have anything to do with a DNS server, right?

What else can I do or check to make these 5 seconds disappear? Thank you very much!

**Update**
As someone pointed me to the /etc/resolv.conf file, this it's the content (apart from some commented out lines):

```
domain hitronhub.home
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Is it ok? What is `hitronhub.home`?

**Update**

Here is the result of `scutil --dns`

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : hitronhub.home
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.8
  nameserver[1] : 8.8.4.4
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : Reachable

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  order    : 301000

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : hitronhub.home
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.8
  nameserver[1] : 8.8.4.4
  if_index : 5 (en1)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : Reachable
```

Comment: Which web browser?  Safari?  It could be anti-phishing, could be DNS lookups against the first DNS nameserver are not responding.  Run `scutil --dns` from a terminal to very the settings for *resolver #1*.  Past that, install Wireshark and sniff the traffic to see what's going over the wire.

Comment: I've testet in Safari and Chrome. I'll post the result of `scutil --dns` as an update in the original question as I'm not sure what it says. I'll try Wireshark. Thanks so far!

Comment: … or (and more likely) [it could be nothing to do with the DNS whatsoever](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-narrow-problem-locus.html).  Your best course of action is to tell the world what is in the "Network" tab of Google Chrome's developer tools, so the world can explain what that means and what the diagnostic tool reveals.

Answer (score 1):

Install Firebug (browser extension); open it, and click on the Net tab. Load a page, and see if there are any processes taking a particularly long time.

Comment: I've tried with Chrome. There are processes called "waiting", taking 2+ seconds, "connecting" and "blocking" each half a second. Thanks!